# NSArray from NSString of values vs NSArray of NSStrings

Tags: objective-c

Consider this simple piece of demonstration code, meant to provide a simple way of creating color gradient arrays for UIButtons:

```
    NSString *gradientString=@"#b62f5a, #b32755, #b01f4f, #ad1449, #aa0444";
    NSArray *gradientArray = [gradientString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

    NSArray *newGradientArray=  [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"#b62f5a", @"#b32755", @"#b01f4f", @"#ad1449", @"#aa0444", nil]; // works

    NSMutableArray *final=[NSMutableArray array];
    for(id cstr in newGradientArray){
        [final addObject:(id)[[self colorFromHexString:cstr] CGColor]];
    }
    [final addObject:[NSNull null]];

    btn.titleLabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    // Set the button Background Color
    CAGradientLayer *btnGradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    btnGradient.frame = btn.bounds;
    btnGradient.colors = final;
    btnGradient.opacity=0.9f;
// etc, etc button code below
```

As shown above, using:

```
    for(id cstr in newGradientArray)
```

This works correctly.  Making one small change to:

```
    for(id cstr in gradientArray)
```

Does not work.

For reference, this is colorFromHexString:

```
- (UIColor *)colorFromHexString:(NSString *)hexString {
    unsigned rgbValue = 0;
    hexString=hexString.uppercaseString;
    NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:hexString];
    [scanner setScanLocation:1]; // bypass '#' character
    [scanner scanHexInt:&rgbValue];
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16)/255.0 green:((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8)/255.0 blue:(rgbValue & 0xFF)/255.0 alpha:1.0];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the two first lines.

```
NSString *gradientString=@"#b62f5a, #b32755, #b01f4f, #ad1449, #aa0444";
NSArray *gradientArray = [gradientString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

gradientArray contains: `[@"#b62f5a", @" #b32755", @" #b01f4f", @" #ad1449", @" #aa0444"]`

Remove all the spaces from  `@"#b62f5a, #b32755, #b01f4f, #ad1449, #aa0444"` and it should work as intended

Edit: Or as rmaddy suggested change the separator to `@", "`

Comment: Or change the separator to `@", "`.